Is there an equivalent of system() for capturing commands outputs or programs running in terminal buffers?
I am aware that system() capture the output of shell commands.
I am wondering if there is a similar command for capturing the output of commands sent to other type of interpreters running in terminal buffers.
For example, say that I have a python console running on a terminal buffer and I want to capture the output of the Python command print("hello world"), is there any command that allows me that?
I wish a generic command that also applies to other interpreters like e.g. gdb, etc.
At the moment, I know how to send commands (e.g. term_sendkeys(python_term_buf_nr, 'print("hello world\n")', where python_term_buffer_nr is a buffer number running Python interpreter), but then I don't know how to capture their output.

I think :help term_getline() is the closest you can get to what you want. :help term_dumpwrite() is another possibility.

Usch! I feel like that my script is going to be very complex...

Are you sure a terminal buffer is what you want? You might be better off with a job instead if you're communicating over stdin/out
